# Create a structure node with unknown number of links

Tags: c, graph, structure

I've worked on linked-lists, Binary trees where we already know the number of links a node can have.
for eg., a doubly linked-list has 2 so as a binary tree.
But when it comes to Graphs, a node can be liked to n number of other nodes, so my question is how do I declare a structure for the node with an unknown number of links.

Binary Tree structure

```
struct node{
    node* left;
    node* right;
    int data;
}
```

Singly-linked list

```
struct node{
    node* link;
    int data;
}
```

[image: An example graph to which I want to create a structure]

Here in this graph node "2" has two links, whereas node "4" has three.

I'm new to C, so please bear with my lack of knowledge on these topics, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I'm new to C,` yet you tagged your question with both C++ and C. C and C++ are _different languages_. Are you interested in C __or__ are you interested in C++? Please pick one.

Comment: @IanAbott Thanks for callling me out on a mistake. Yes I missed a difference between a tree and a more generic graph. Yes that something is implied by "acyclic" for a tree and "cyclic" in a graph like OPs. Chapeau! I should have checked against the example straight away. Good style of showing persistence and staying matter of fact at the same time. For anybody interested in the details of my mistake: a sibling of a node, with respect to also being a child of the same parent, is not enough to cover that the two nodes might NOT be siblings in being childs of a different node in a (cyclic) graph.

Answer (score 4):

> how do I declare a structure for the node with an unknown number of links.

Create a pointer to an dynamically allocated array of pointers to nodes.

```
struct node {
    /// array of pointers to nodes we link to
    node **link;
    /// count of links
    size_t link_cnt;

    int data;
};
```

Then `link` points to a dynamically allocated array of pointers to nodes - it's an array of "links". The `link_cnt` can be used to track count of links in the link array.

```
// example of linking two nodes in one direction.
void node_link_to_node(struct node *this, struct node *other) {
   void *p = realloc(this->link, sizeof(*this->link) * (this->link_cnt + 1));
   if (p == NULL) abort();
   this->link = p;
   this->link[this->link_cnt] = other;
   this->link_cnt++;
}
```

I have written this code with C in mind.

Comment: Using C++ keywords in C code is somewhat error prone, especially when the OP explicitly tagged the question with both languages. Furthermore you use `node` as a type name but do not define `node` as `typedef struct node node;` which is not implicit in C.